# Implement Parent-Child relationship logic based on the logic given below

Tags: javascript, recursion, parent-child

The below logic has to be implemented and I am unable to proceed with it,

Logic :

```
A has a child B 
B has a child C 
C has a child D 
D doesn’t have any child 
E doesn’t have any child
```

On selection of any parent, a list of a potential child for that particular selected parent should be added in a list.

For the above scenario, the desired outputs are as shown below,

On selection of parent A, the list of children contain B, C, D, and
E.

On selection of parent B, the list of children contains C, D, and E.
A cannot be a child of B as B is already a child of A, hence A will not be listed.

On selection of parent C, the list of children contain D and E.
B cannot be a child of C as C is already a child of B, A cannot be a child of C as B is a child of Stream A. Hence A and B will not be
listed.

On selection of parent D, the list of children E.
C cannot be a child of D as D is already a child of C, B cannot be a child of D as B is a child of C, A cannot be a child of D as A has a
child B. Hence A, B, and C will not be listed.

On selection of E, the list of children contains A, B, C and D.

Please help me with implementing this logic.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried with recursion and I am very sure that the code is wrong. That’s the reason I haven’t added the code here.

Comment: That's how SO generally works.  You show people what you're trying, and they suggest fixes.  This is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each node has at most one parent, the following logic should do the job:

```
var allNodes = [A, B, C, D, E]

function onNodeSelect(node) {
  var possibleChildren = allNodes
  possibleChildren.remove(node)

  var currentNode = node
  while (currentNode.hasParent) {
    currentNode = node.parent
    possibleChildren.remove(currentNode)
  }

  return possibleChildren
}
```